# how to create a batch file to edit sql query

Tags: batch-processing, batch-file

I need to create a batch file which should be parameterised

my Query

```
select * from glob2("parameterised value what the user is entering")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set /p` to query the user for input:

```
set /p value=Enter something:
```

You can then subsequently use the variable; in this case `%value%`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you can access the command line parameters by referring to %1 %2 etc.

Read `HELP CALL` and try this

```
@echo off
echo QUERY SELECT * FROM GLOB2 WHERE NAME="%1"
```